# I don't know how to navigate genymotion in the terminal

Tags: android

i have downloaded the genymotion-2.2.0_x86.bin but dont know how to go by it.please help.
when i run the chmod +x command line it tells me "no command found" and that no genymotion directory found

Comment: where is `genymotion-2.2.0_x86.bin` file  located?

Comment: To be able to download it, you need to sign up for an account @ https://cloud.genymotion.com

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please, could you put some of your time to read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that you've downloaded the right file for your architecture:

32bit:

```
chmod +x genymotion-2.2.0_x86.bin
./genymotion-2.2.0_x86.bin
```

64bit:

```
chmod +x genymotion-2.2.0_x64.bin
./genymotion-2.2.0_x64.bin
```

Comment: should i hit enter after typing the first line because anytime i try hitting enter the terminal requests my password to proceed and if i enter the password...ops!!! the cannot find directory message pops up agau

Comment: Usually downloaded files are in ~/Downloads. So first type `cd Downloads` and then the two (independent) commands I provided in my answer (hit enter after each of them).

Comment: waowww...u are a genius...it worked liked magic....my warmest gratitude Sylvain Pineau

Comment: Could you please accept my answer? Thanks (See http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers)